# What is fourcc code for YUV420/YUV422 10 bit semi planar formats

Tags: video, yuv, color-space

Could readers please suggest me right fourcc codes to represent

```
YUV420 10 bit semi-planar
YUV422 10 bit semi-planar
```

The data looks like below in memory:

```
2:10:10:10 2:Y2:Y1:Y0
2:10:10:10 2:U1:V0:U0
```

3 components packed in 4 bytes

Comment: Don't think I understand what you are asking. Have a look at [vooya](http://www.offminor.de/) which can play most of the available YCbCr formats out there. Also try `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this [page](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb970578) can help.

Regarding this table from the page

> FOURCC Description
>   P016   Planar, 4:2:0, 16-bit.
>   P010   Planar, 4:2:0, 10-bit.
>   P216   Planar, 4:2:2, 16-bit.
>   P210   Planar, 4:2:2, 10-bit.
>   Y216   Packed, 4:2:2, 16-bit.
>   Y210   Packed, 4:2:2, 10-bit.
>   Y416   Packed, 4:4:4, 16-bit
>   Y410   Packed, 4:4:4, 10-bit.

your colorspace named P010 or P210. Dispite this fourcc color space described as Planar, below it is showed as semi-planar.

> P016 and P010
>   In these two formats, all Y samples appear first in memory as an array of WORDs with an even number of lines. The surface stride can be larger than the width of the Y plane. This array is followed immediately by an array of WORDs that contains interleaved U and V samples, as shown in the following diagram.
>   [Diagram showing P016 and P010 pixel layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsP6m.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think I understand what you are asking. Have a look at [vooya](http://www.offminor.de/) which can play most of the available YCbCr formats out there. Also try `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` to list the available formats.

For example to play the 10bpp sequences provided by the HEVC standardization which are in 4:2:0 10bpp, you can use the following ffmpeg command:

```
$ ffplay -video_size 2560x1600 -pixel_format yuv420p10le SteamLocomotiveTrain_2560x1600_60_10bit_crop.yuv
```

So, in "ffmpeg-speach", the format is called `yuv420p10le`, where `le` is little-endian.

Comment: I am looking for fourcc codes for 10 bit formats. for e.g. NV12 is a fourcc code for YUV420 8 bit semi planar.

Comment: Yeah, I have not figured out what 'le' means until now.